Formula for calculating overtime pay in a single function in google sheets
I'm trying to streamline my hourly invoice for some of my clients and struggling with the overtime calculation, starting to wonder if this is a pipe dream.
The clients don't care about time in/out, just the hours worked for the day so here's how I have my invoice sheet set up:



Date (B15)
Project (C15)
Hours (E15)
Rate (F15)
Total Pay (G15)



Here's what I want the function to do:
Check E15 to see if there are more than 8 hours shown

if no, multiply Hours by Rate and spit out the pay in Total Pay

if yes, multiply Hours by Rate for the first 8, then multiply remaining Hours by (1.5 x Rate), then add those together and pop the Total Pay


The more I think about this, the more it feels like a pipe dream.
Is there a simple solution to this complicated wish list?

See OT.

For an invoice, presumably, there are multiple entries.

Example array formula that will generate a 3-column array for all the hours in E15:E (or whatever range you set).

Place the formula in G14 (highlighted in the table below).

Overtime is represented by ot/OT in the formula.


={"Reg", "OT", "Total Pay";
  MAP(E15:E, F15:F, LAMBDA(hr, wg, LET(
    ot,MAX(hr-8,0),  
    IF(hr, {hr-ot, ot, wg*(hr+ot/2)},))))} 

IF  LAMBDA  LET  MAP  MAX




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




14

Date
Project

Hours
Rate
Reg
OT
Total Pay


15

Mon 09/16/2024
worldPeace

7
$10
7

$70


16

Tue 09/17/2024
GlobalDom.

9.25
$10
8
1.25
$98.75


17

Wed 09/18/2024
GlobalDom.

10
$10
8
2
$110


18

Thu 09/19/2024
GlobalDom.

4
$10
4

$40


19

Fri 09/20/2024
worldPeace

6
$10
6

$60


20

Mon 09/23/2024
worldPeace

15
$10
8
7
$185


21

Tue 09/24/2024
GlobalDom.

7.5
$10
7.5

$75


22

Wed 09/25/2024
worldPeace

0
$10





23

Thu 09/26/2024
GlobalDom.

5
$10
5

$50


24

Fri 09/27/2024
GlobalDom.

7
$10
7

$70




@doubleunary Ty for your edit simplifying the formula.

Use this pattern:
=min(8, E15) * HoursPayRate + max(0, E15 - 8) * 1.5 * HoursPayRate

Replace HoursPayRate with a reference to the cell where you have the hourly pay rate.
See min() and max().
